# SWIFT 4.2: IGRPhotoTweaks cropAction plus CIPerspectiveCorrection

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

IOS 11+, Swift 4.2.  I'm using IGRPhotoTweaks for crop and rotate. It works perfectly for those needs.

Now I'm trying to incorporate perspective correction and a little lost.  It seems so simple, I can get both to work separately, but not in concert.

My process is:

in my ticket editing view controller:

```
 extension TicketEditViewController: IGRPhotoTweakViewControllerDelegate {
    func photoTweaksController(_ controller: IGRPhotoTweakViewController, didFinishWithCroppedImage croppedImage: UIImage) {
        _ = controller.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

        self.takenImage = croppedImage

    }

    func photoTweaksControllerDidCancel(_ controller: IGRPhotoTweakViewController) {
        _ = controller.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

When I get didFinishWithCroppedImage, I have a croppedImage and then the original image.

The question is: how do I then apply a perspective on this cropped image of a ticket that has been cropped to a region within the ticket ?

This is my code snippet (taken from https://github.com/kronik/smartcrop ).  It works on the full ticket on a different background, but when I try to pass in just a cropped region of a ticket, it does not get any features().

```
    let docImage = CIImage(image: originalImage!)!
    var rect: CIRectangleFeature = CIRectangleFeature()        
    if let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle,
                                 context: ciContext,
                                 options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]) {

        let features = detector.features(in: docImage)
        if features.first != nil {
        rect = detector.features(in: docImage).first as! CIRectangleFeature
        } else {
            nextStepButton.setTitle("Error, no points detected", for: .normal)
            return
        }
    }

    let perspectiveCorrection = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection")!
    let docImage = CIImage(image: originalImage!)!

    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint:rect.topLeft),
                                   forKey: "inputTopLeft")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint:rect.topRight),
                                   forKey: "inputTopRight")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint:rect.bottomRight),
                                   forKey: "inputBottomRight")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint:rect.bottomLeft),
                                   forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(docImage,
                                   forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let outputImage = perspectiveCorrection.outputImage

    let updatedImage = UIImage(ciImage: outputImage!, scale: originalImage!.scale, orientation: .up)
```

How can I get the proper "rect" from  UIImage (croppedImage) from IGRTweaks and pass it into perspectiveCorrection?